# Can anyone read a video spectrogram and understand it?

Tags: phonetics

Is it known if there have been people that can visually digest a spectrogram of speech in time, as a video, and learn to read it in real time, like text? (Or vice versa, translating images to sounds via an inverse spectrogram, and being able to “see” what the sound depicts?)

And/or being able to draw a spectrogram manually from heard speech?